# Monitor active directory changes

Tags: active-directory

What is a good tool to monitor certain Active Directory changes? For example: We would like to see a weekly report of: newly created users, users added to groups, locked out users, domain admins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Microsoft Active Directory Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx) allows you to take snapshots of Active Directory and compare them.  I'm not sure if you can use it to automatically generate reports periodically, but it is a nice tool for monitoring changes at all levels.

If you are into scripting, you may be able to use [dsquery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732952(WS.10).aspx) to get the specific info you need.  See [the answer to this other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/194654/how-do-i-find-new-active-directory-accounts-that-have-been-made-in-the-last-90-da/194660#194660) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case scom with ACS is a good solution.